# Exporting from SQL Server to Excel with column headers?

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2005, export

I have a query that has approximately 20 columns and I would like to export this to an Excel file with the column headers.

I thought this would be easy to figure out but no luck! I searched the web and found one suggestion that did not end up working so I am stuck.

Comment: is this a onetime export or you trying to setup a job?

Comment: Are you using Enterprise Manager or Management Studio?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I typically do this by simply click the upper left corner in the results grid, copy, and then paste into Excel.  There is one catch, you need to go into options->query results-> SQL Server->results to grid (or text if you want to save to file for import into excel) and turn on include column headers when copying or saving  the results.  I find this works great.

Answer (score 30):

Tools --> Options, Select "Query Results" --> "SQL Server" --> "Results to Grid" and "Results to Text" (images below):

[image]

[image]

Comment: You will need to restart SQL Server Management Studio for the settings to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

This script rocks
[BCP to Export data to excel](http://dotnetkeeda.blogspot.in/2009/09/bcp-command-to-export-data-to-excel.html)

Answer (score 1):

That is the default if you use the Import/Export wizard. You can also save this out to an SSIS package if you want to customize the export.

Comment: Thanks Gregory, unfortunately I can't use the wizard since I have to automate to run every day.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but my suggestion is not obvious in MS-SSMS so I'm passing it on.

RIGHT click on the upper left corner of the results grid and select 'Save Results As' and CSV and TXT formats are the two choices in 'Save as Type'.

This works best when the query results are too big for 'cut and paste' used for smaller query results.