# Query to export SQL Server to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, export, export-to-excel, xls

I'm trying to export data in SQL Server to Excel. Here is my code :

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(255)
SET @cmd = 'bcp "My Select Query Here" queryout "My Excel File Path Here" -U sqluserHere -P sqlpasswordHere -c'
Exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

It works perfectly but the column name is not also exported, and I need it.

How can I get the column name in the first row in my Excel?

Comment: I don't know how do this by code. But, you can read this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639886/from-sql-server-how-can-i-export-to-excel-with-the-column-headers. Hope it help!

Comment: There is an issue at Microsoft Connect about that: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/288800/bcp-out-to-include-field-columns-names

Comment: thanks for answering :) i found this http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926 and it works perfectly :)